# AJAX trigger remote script then check for success-response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I've been searching my brains out but I can't seem to wrap my head around the little help I find.

I'm running a database that is being fed by data from another DB. The csv transport is handled by a third party server providing executable "flows" which compile and deliver the data.

I have a php script to handle the request (can't be done directly via Javascript because of the missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header). But this runs nicely. I can trigger the flow.

This is not the problem though.
What I want to do: trigger the flow @onClick of a button with something like this:

```
function trigger_func(flowID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: './ajaxPHP_handler.php',
        data: "flowid="+flowID,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            var jsonResult  =   jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(jsonResult.runID);
        }
    });
}
```

With the flowID and the resulting runID I want to check back like every second or so.

```
function check_status(flowID, runID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: './ajaxPHP_handler.php',
        data: "flowid="+flowID+"&action=status&runId="+runID,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){...}
    });
}
```

This will return the status / progress of the flow.
It will start for a few seconds with status==null, then go on to status=='running' and finally status=='success'.
I have gotten check_status() to run for i.e. 15 times with a setTimeout in a for loop within the success-function of trigger_func() and it works fine too.
But I cannot for the life of me figure out how I would link this stuff together to have it checking until status is 'success' and then stop checking, update page content and so on...

I have also fiddled with something like

```
trigger_func(id).done(function(result){
console.log(result);
});
```

This works too but still I can't think my way further to the checking every second until 'success'. I guess it comes down to getting the variable 'status' back into my loop so I can break it.

Maybe someone knows of a comprehensible example somewhere online...

Comment: Let me understand, basically you want to make a periodic ajax request until the success status is returned, at that point it should stop. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. This is what I'd like to do 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function periodically_check_status_until_success(flowID, runID) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: './ajaxPHP_handler.php',
            data: { flowid: flowID, action: status, runId: runID },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                 if (result != 'success') {
                     periodically_check_status_until_success(flowID, runID);
                 }
            }
        });
    }, 5000); // Five seconds
}
```

Note: You can use an object for the `data` option, rather than concatenate the string yourself.

Comment: I think I got it running like this. :)
Gosh, and it was so easy .... Thanks very much for the kick in the thought process :)

I set the timeout to 1000 so the delay in the first run of check_status() doesn't matter. The flow is always still in "pending" status during the first few seconds.

Thanks also to the other commenters. This really is an awesome community here and has become my number one resource when I need to look up ideas... :)

Answer (score 0):

ajax are async so you have to manage by this via some 3rd party variable

Like Init with value 0

```
var _status = 0
```

than change it on your first call set it 1

```
function trigger_func(flowID) {
 $.ajax({
     url: './ajaxPHP_handler.php',
     data: "flowid="+flowID,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result) {
         var jsonResult  =   jQuery.parseJSON(result);
         console.log(jsonResult.runID);
          check_status(flowID, runID);
     }
 });
}



 function check_status(flowID, runID) {
 $.ajax({
     url: './ajaxPHP_handler.php',
     data: "flowid="+flowID+"&action=status&runId="+runID,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result){
        //at end status=='success'.
          if(status=='success'){
              // end part 
           }else{// running 
               check_status(flowID, runID);
           }

          // clear timeout will stop that time interval after success  
     }
 });
 }
```

Comment: Never use setTimeout outside an ajax call. Use the success callback to trigger the next round

Comment: Now it is the same as I suggested

Comment: yes but what happen when calls go in infinite ...at some point developer need to do some secure code  ..so he can handle that situation also

Answer (score 0):

So just keep calling it

```
var flowID, runID;
function trigger_func(flowID) {
  $.ajax({
    url: './ajaxPHP_handler.php',
    data: "flowid="+flowID,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        var jsonResult  =   jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        runID= jsonResult.runID;
        check_status();
    }
  });
}

function check_status() {
  $.ajax({
    url: './ajaxPHP_handler.php',
    data: "flowid="+flowID+"&action=status&runId="+runID,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
      if (result is not what you want) {
        setTimeout(check_status,1000);
      }
    }
  });
}
```